# WHERE statement after a UNION in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I apply a WHERE statement after a UNION in SQL/MySQL?

Answer (score 168, accepted):

If you want to apply the WHERE clause to the result of the UNION, then you have to embed the UNION in the FROM clause:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT * FROM TableA
        UNION
        SELECT * FROM TableB
       ) AS U
 WHERE U.Col1 = ...
```

I'm assuming TableA and TableB are union-compatible.  You could also apply a WHERE clause to each of the individual SELECT statements in the UNION, of course.

Comment: Any idea if MySQL will push the predicate into the individual statements?

Comment: @Martin: it might - it might not.  You'd have to look at the query plan.  It also depends on the WHERE clause conditions.

Comment: @Martin, Don't hope too much. Having us to do something like this shows just how dumb MySQL is....

Comment: works flawlessly!

Answer (score 27):

You probably need to wrap the `UNION` in a sub-`SELECT` and apply the `WHERE` clause afterward:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Field1 = Value1
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE Field1 = Value2
) AS t WHERE Field2 = Value3
```

Basically, the `UNION` is looking for two complete `SELECT` statements to combine, and the `WHERE` clause is part of the `SELECT` statement.

It may make more sense to apply the outer `WHERE` clause to both of the inner queries.  You'll probably want to benchmark the performance of both approaches and see which works better for you.

Comment: works flawlessly!

Answer (score 0):

```
select column1..... from table1
where column1=''
union
select column1..... from table2
where column1= ''
```