# mysql query two tables, UNION and where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, union, where-clause

I have two tables.

I query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
   Select requester_name,receiver_name from poem_authors_follow_requests  as one 
UNION 
Select requester_name,receiver_name from poem_authors_friend_requests as two 
) as u 
where (LOWER(requester_name)=LOWER('user1') or LOWER(receiver_name)=LOWER('user1'))
```

I am using UNION because i want to get distinct values for each user if a user exists in the first table and in the second.

For example:

```
table1

nameofuser
peter

table2

nameofuser
peter
```

if peter is on either table i should get the name one time because it exists on both tables.

Still i get one row from first table and a second from table number two. What is wrong?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Are the columns in both of your tables of the same time? Maybe in one table the column is of type `char`and in the other it's of type `varchar`there might me some spaces....

Comment: nop they are both the same type of fields

Comment: In your where statement, you probably want to reference the "u" before each field... so `where (LOWER(u.requester_name) = ...` this is simlar to the answer you can see in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5452233/where-statement-after-a-union-in-sql

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are two problems with your SQL:

1. (THis is **not** the question, but should be considered) by using `WHERE` over the `UNION` instead of the tables, you create a performance nightmare: MySQL will create a temporary table containing the `UNION`, then query it over the `WHERE`. Using a calculation on a field (`LOWER(requester_name)`) makes this even worse.
2. The reason you get two rows is, that `UNION DISTINCT` will only suppress real duplicates, so the tuple `(someuser,peter)` and the tuple `(someotheruser, peter)` will result in duplication.

**Edit**

To make `(someuser, peter)` a duplicate of `(peter, someuser)` you could use:

```
SELECT
  IF(requester_name='peter', receiver_name, requester_name) AS otheruser
FROM
  ...
UNION
SELECT
  IF(requester_name='peter', receiver_name, requester_name) AS otheruser
FROM
  ...
```

So you only select `someuser` which you already know : `peter`

Comment: Thanks for telling me Eugen Rieck you were right it finds duplicates as you said...could you please tell me if there is a way to solve this? (someuser,peter) or (peter,someuser) should be a duplicate in my case.

Answer (score 2):

You need the where clause on *both* selects:

```
select requester_name, receiver_name
from poem_authors_follow_requests
where LOWER(requester_name) = LOWER('user1') or LOWER(receiver_name) = LOWER('user1')
union
select requester_name, receiver_name
from poem_authors_friend_requests
where LOWER(requester_name) = LOWER('user1') or LOWER(receiver_name) = LOWER('user1')
```

The two queries are independent of each other, so you shouldn't try to connect them other than by `union`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use UNION if you want to select rows one after the other from several tables or several sets of rows from a single table all as a single result set.
UNION is available as of MySQL 4.0. This section illustrates how to use it.
Suppose you have two tables that list prospective and actual customers, a third that lists vendors from whom you purchase supplies, and you want to create a single mailing list by merging names and addresses from all three tables. UNION provides a way to do this. Assume the three tables have the following contents:

http://w3webtutorial.blogspot.com/2013/11/union-in-mysql.html

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the union before and then applying the where clause. So you would get a unique combination of "requester_name,receiver_name" and then the where clause would apply. Apply the where clause in each select...

```
Select requester_name,receiver_name from poem_authors_follow_requests
where (LOWER(requester_name)=LOWER('user1')
        or LOWER(receiver_name)=LOWER('user1'))
UNION 
Select requester_name,receiver_name from poem_authors_friend_requests 
where (LOWER(requester_name)=LOWER('user1')
        or LOWER(receiver_name)=LOWER('user1'))
```

Answer (score 0):

In your where statement, reference the alias "u" for each field refence in your where statement.

So the beginning of your where statement would be like: `where (LOWER(u.requester_name) = ...`

This is simlar to the answer you can see in: [WHERE statement after a UNION in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5452233/where-statement-after-a-union-in-sql)

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to use the `INTERSECT` keyword instead of doing a nested query on a `UNION`.

```
SELECT member_id, name FROM a
INTERSECT
SELECT member_id, name FROM b
```

can simply be rewritten to

```
SELECT a.member_id, a.name
FROM a INNER JOIN b
USING (member_id, name)
```

http://www.bitbybit.dk/carsten/blog/?p=71

Comment: MySQL does not support the `INTERSECT` keyword!