# Laravel add where clause to union result

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, union

I'm doing a union on two queries, and I want to add a where clause to the result, but the where clause is added only to the first query. how can I fix that?

```
    $notifications = DB::table('notifications')
        ->select(DB::raw("notifications.uuid ,notifications.brand_id" ))
    $posts = DB::table('posts')
        ->select(DB::raw("posts.uuid ,posts.brand_id" ))
        ->unionAll ($notifications)
        ->orderBy('created_at' , 'desc')
        ->where('brand_ids' , '=' , '2')
    $result  = $posts->get();
```

I want this line

```
           ->where('brand_id' , '=' , '2')
```

to be added to the whole union, but it is added only to one of the queries.

Comment: Can't you add the `->where('brand_id', '=', '2')` on both queries, and for the second before the `unionAll` (and remove the `brand_ids` where clause) ?

Comment: As already mentioned you need to use subquery. I was able to do that using the solution from the laracasts reply https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/cant-use-where-clause-after-union-of-2-queries?page=1&replyId=897198

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is a better way, but this works for me:

```
$notifications = DB::table('notifications')
                ->select(DB::raw("notifications.uuid ,notifications.brand_id"));
$posts = DB::table('posts')
        ->select(DB::raw("posts.uuid ,posts.brand_id"))
        ->unionAll($notifications)
        ->orderBy('created_at' , 'desc');
$result = DB::table(DB::raw("({$posts->toSql()}) as posts"))
                ->mergeBindings($posts)
                ->where('brand_id', '2')
                ->get();
```

Comment: Wish there was a better way

Answer (score 0):

That is down to MYSQL rather than Laravel.

As you can see from the example here if you want to do a where after a union, it needs to be done as a subquery.
[WHERE statement after a UNION in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5452233/where-statement-after-a-union-in-sql)

Let me hope this solution helps anyone.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your query is invalid because you order the results by `created_at` and you did not select this column. I wish my code helps you

```
$notifications = DB::table('notifications')
    ->select(DB::raw("uuid, brand_id, created_at"))
    ->where('brand_id', 2);

DB::table('posts')
    ->select(DB::raw("uuid, brand_id, created_at"))
    ->unionAll($notifications)
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
    ->where('brand_id', 2)
    ->dd();
```

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel, the where clause is applied only to the last segment of the query builder chain. If you want to apply a where condition to the entire union result, you can use a subquery.

```
$notifications = DB::table('notifications')
    ->select(DB::raw("notifications.uuid, notifications.brand_id"));

$posts = DB::table('posts')
    ->select(DB::raw("posts.uuid, posts.brand_id"))
    ->unionAll($notifications);

$result = DB::table(DB::raw("({$posts->toSql()}) as sub"))
    ->mergeBindings($posts)
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->where('brand_id', '=', '2')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a where clause to the entire union instead of just one query, you need to use a subquery. Here's an example of how you can modify your code:

```
$notifications = DB::table('notifications')
    ->select(DB::raw("notifications.uuid, notifications.brand_id"));

$posts = DB::table('posts')
    ->select(DB::raw("posts.uuid, posts.brand_id"))
    ->unionAll($notifications);

$result = DB::table(DB::raw("({$posts->toSql()}) as combined"))
    ->mergeBindings($posts) // This is important to merge the bindings
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->where('brand_id', '=', '2')
    ->get();
```

I use a subquery by using DB::raw("({$posts->toSql()}) as combined") and mergeBindings($posts) to ensure that bindings are properly merged. The where clause is then applied to the entire result set.