# Search query after Union

Tags: mysql, datatable, laravel-5, query-builder

I have this method to process serverside data for Bootstrap Datatables

```
public function datatable(Request $request)
{
    $organizations = DB::table('organizations')
        ->join('customers', function ($join) 
        {
            $join->on('organizations.id', '=', 'customers.customer_id')
                ->where('customers.customer_class', '=', 'Organization');
        })
        ->select([
            'customers.id',
            'organizations.name',
        ]);

    $contacts = DB::table('contacts')
        ->join('customers', function ($join) 
        {
            $join->on('contacts.id', '=', 'customers.customer_id')
                ->where('customers.customer_class', '=', 'Contact');
        })
        ->select([
            'customers.id',
            'contacts.name',
        ]);

    $customers = $organizations->union($contacts);

    return Datatables::of($customers)
        ->editColumn('name', function($customers) {
            return '<a href="'.route('customers.show', $customers->id).'">'.$customers->name.'</a>';
        })
        ->make(true);
}
```

I guess what DataTables does is performs WHERE LIKE search on a supplied query.
The problem is that whenecer I try to perform search, it returns random results. The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5452266/1818343) suggests that I have to have to embed the UNION in the FROM clause,  like

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT * FROM TableA
        UNION
        SELECT * FROM TableB
       ) AS U
 WHERE U.Col1 = ...
```

But I can't wrap my head aroud how to that in a Laravel Query Builder.

In case it's relevant, here's JS code

```
$(function () {
    $('#customer-table').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        bfilter: false,
        ajax: "{{route('customers.datatable')}}",
        columns: [
            { data: 'name'},
        ]
    });

});
```

Comment: Can you show the errors you are getting please

Comment: There are no errors. The problem is that search results are not consistent with search string

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this put mysql query as whole in quotes as below,

DB:raw('SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT * FROM TableA
        UNION
        SELECT * FROM TableB
       ) AS U
 WHERE U.Col1 = ...')->get();

This will give the desired result.

Comment: In Laravel 5.2 class `Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression` doesn't have mothod `get` https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Query/Expression.html